# Awk or Sed Command to Fix Bad JSON formatting?

Tags: json, awk, sed

Okay, so I've got over a hundred JSON files with predictable bad formatting in several places per file.

Instead of using `[ ]` to indicate an array, they use `{ }` instead.

For example:

```
"grid": {
"C1", "D1", "E1", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "C6", "D6", "E6"
},
```

Each file has multiple arrays in it with this problem, each with a different key.

I came up with this to fix the above example, but it isn't very universal:

```
sed 's/^\t\t"grid": {/^\t\t"grid: [/; s/"E6" },$/"E6" ],/' myfile.json
```

I also tried writing a more complicated awk script, something along these lines:

```
awk -i '/grid/ { gsub("{",{["); gsub("}","]") print $0 }' myfile.json
```

But it replaced the contents of myfile.json to be *only* the row that contained the string "grid".

Is there a reliable one-liner to fix this issue?

Comment: Does it have to be universal? Are you continuously going to get a new batch of these files from somewhere that need repair? If so, is there no way to fix the problem upstream, where they are generated?

Comment: @Kaz, no, I'm creating all the JSON files myself by hand converting non-digital  records. So I am the "upsteam" problem, and I have already fixed it. :) I am just trying to save work for myself in fixing the existing problems.

Comment: Awk doesn't print anything by default. However, if a condition-action pair omits the action, then the `{ print }` action is implicit.  Note that `gsub` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Newer versions of GNU Awk don't have an `-i` option for "in place"; rather, there is `-i <include-file>`. You can use `-i inplace` to load the inplace extension.  The semantics is still the same; the Awk produces output and that output replaces the file. If nothing is printed, the file will be empty.

Comment: not sure if this will give the the completely fixed output you need, but change to `awk -i '{ ....code ...}1' file`  The added `1` will get the other lines to print. Also agree about using `-i`, better to get in the habit of `awk 'code' file >file.fix && mv file.fix file`. There is no system economy in using `inplace` options, there is alway a temp file created. Good luck

Comment: Just for the record: In order to format JSON, you use `jq` or similar tools. The problem here is not bad formatting, but simply that the file is not (valid) JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose following GNU `AWK` solution, let `file.json` content be

```
{"hello": 1,
"grid": {"C1", "D1", "E1", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "C6", "D6", "E6"},
"something": "else"}
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}/grid/&&match($0,/\{[^}]*\}/){$RSTART="[";$(RSTART+RLENGTH-1)="]"}{print}' file.json
```

gives output

```
{"hello": 1,
"grid": ["C1", "D1", "E1", "C2", "D2", "E2", "F2", "B3", "C3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "F4", "C5", "D5", "E5", "F5", "C6", "D6", "E6"],
"something": "else"}
```

Explanation: firstly I inform GNU `AWK` that field is any single character (`.`) and output field separator (`OFS`) is empty string (without that there would be unwanted spaces in output) then for each line with `grid` in it and containing literal `{` followed by zero or more (`*`) non (`^`) `}` and literal `}`, I replace first (`$RSTART`) character of what was matched using `[` and last (`$(RSTART+RLENGTH-1)`) character of what was matched using `]`, for each line, altered or not, I `print` it. Note that I use [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function rather than using just regular expression as I then use `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` which are set by this variable. Note that return value of `match` is used as part of condition so if there will be `grid` in line but not `{`...`}` then said line will remain unchanged.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Fails for broken arrays split over multiple lines, and ones with a single element: https://ideone.com/zo3Fr3

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="test.json"
JSON="$(sed -E 's/([}{])/\n\1\n/g' $FILE)"
while :; do
    JQTEST=$(jq  '.' <<<"$JSON" 2>&1|grep "Objects must consist of key:value pairs at line")
    rc=$?
    if [ $rc -eq 0 ]; then 
        LINE=$(sed -E "s/.* line ([0-9]+), .*/\1/" <<<"$JQTEST")
        COL=$(sed -E "s/.* column ([0-9]+)$/\1/" <<<"$JQTEST")
        [ "$COL" -ne 1 ] && LINE=$((LINE-1)) 
        JSON=$(sed -E "$LINE s/\{/[/; $LINE s/}/]/" <<<"$JSON")
    else
      jq  '.' <<<"$JSON" # > "new_${FILE}" or "${FILE}" 
      break
    fi
done

$ cat test.json 
{
"grid1": {"C1", "D1", "E1", "C2"}, 
"grid2": {"C1", "D1", "E1", "C2"}, 
"grid3": {"C1", "D1", "E1", "C2"} 
}


$ script.sh 
{
  "grid1": [
    "C1",
    "D1",
    "E1",
    "C2"
  ],
  "grid2": [
    "C1",
    "D1",
    "E1",
    "C2"
  ],
  "grid3": [
    "C1",
    "D1",
    "E1",
    "C2"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How's this? (Update: probably scroll down to the Perl version near the end.)

```
sed -e 's/{\(\([0-9.]\+\|false\|true\|null\|"[^"]*"\) *[,}]\)/[\1/g' \
    -e 's/\([,[] *\([0-9.]\+\|false\|true\|null\|"[^"]*"\)\)}/\1]/g' file
```

In other words, if the thing after `{"thing"` or before `"thing"}` is a comma or a curly brace (and not a colon, like you would expect in a proper JSON dictionary), switch the curly to a square bracket.
(In the second expression, we will already have replaced any opening curly with a square one, so look for that instead.)

The regex could be made less fugly if your `sed` supports `-E` or `-r`, but unfortunately, this non-standard option is not portable. (In brief, it lets you use the ERE regex dialect instead of BRE, where you mind-numbingly have to backslash grouping parentheses etc.)

Unfortunately, it requires the curly to be on the same line as the contents of the array. Also, like any regex solution, it's not easily able to distinguish between (what looks like JSON inside) a quoted string and actual JSON.

Demo: https://ideone.com/PoZguV

I suppose the same approach could be extended to examine lines which start or end with a lone curly brace, but I'd switch to Awk or Perl for that. In fact, Perl's "slurp mode" `perl -0777` could probably handle the entire input file in one go with minor modifications to the regexes.

```
perl -0777 -pe '
    s/\{(\s*(?:[0-9.]+|false|true|null|"[^"]*")\s*[,}])/[$1/g;
    s/([,[]\s*(?:[0-9.]+|false|true|null|"[^"]*")\s*)\}/$1]/g' file.json
```

This removes any reliance on newlines for analyzing the file, since we read all of it into memory, and rely on `\s` to match any whitespace, including newlines.
If you want to modify the file in-place, Perl also supports the `-i` option, like some versions of `sed`.

Demo: https://ideone.com/0C4gPt